# Laravel Validation: required_with_all condition always passing

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

As per [laravel validation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules):

> **required_with_all:foo,bar,...** The field under validation must be present only if all of the other specified fields are present.

Here is my test:

```
    Route::get('/test/{param}', function($param) {
        $screenRules = array(
            'foo' => 'string',
            'param' => 'required_with_all:foo',

        );

        $validator = Validator::make(array('param' => $param), $screenRules);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($validator->errors());
            echo '</pre>';
            die('Dying now!');
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'All Good!';
            die('Dying now!');
        }
    });
```

I would expect that since I am not passing `foo`, this test should fail. But this test passes when I call my url: **mysite.com/test/mytest**

Similarly, if you reverse the role, like so

```
'param' => 'required_without_all:foo',
```

and pass foo as input

```
array('param' => $param, 'foo' => 'bar')
```

I would expect that since `foo` is present, you cannot have `param` as input. But the test still passes.

In both the cases, I should be seeing errors. So what is going on here?

---

I also know that my validation functions are not wrong, because my other validation works. E.g. add a condition like so:

```
'param' => 'required_with_all:foo|numeric',
```

and it sure does throw an error `The param must be a number.`

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out the answer. I misunderstood the whole `required_if` concept. This answer will help anyone who ever gets stuck in here. The key is reading the laravel documentation again and again ;)

## Concept

For `required_with_all` it says: The field under validation must be present **only** if all of the other specified fields are present.

E.g. `param => required_with_all:foo,bar,...`
means that when foo and bar, both are present, and `param` is not present, then the validation error will occur.

I misunderstood it such that if `param` is there, then it requires `foo` and `bar` to be there too. Its the other way round though as we just saw.

## Alternative

If you need to do a validation as `if param is present, foo must be present` use the **`required_with`** validation rule on foo like so:

```
'param' => 'required_with:foo',
'foo' => 'required_with: param
```

This will ensure that if `foo` or `param`, anyone of them is present, they will require the other to be present too.

## Explanation of my test cases

**First test case**

```
'param' => 'required_with_all:foo'
```

and I passed the following input

```
array('param' => $param)
```

The test case failed because foo not being in the input, did not trigger the validation because the rule says only check when `foo` is present. So instead of passing `param` as input, simply pass `foo` as input and you will see the error that `param` is required when `foo` is present.

**Second test case**

```
'param' => 'required_without_all:foo',
```

and passing input like so:

```
array('param' => $param, 'foo' => 'bar')
```

This validation did not work because it says param is only required when `foo` is not present. However, in my input I have passed foo. Remove both `foo` and `param` and you shall see the error that when foo is not present, param is required.

**How silly of me!**