# laravel validator (required_with_all) chaining

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I use this validator inside my controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'host'        => 'required_with_all:ttl,type,destination|alpha_num|max:32|nullable',
    'ttl'         => 'required_with_all:host,type,destination|integer|between:3000,4800|nullable',
    'type'        => 'required_with_all:host,ttl,destination|integer|between:1,5|nullable',
    'destination' => 'required_with_all:host,ttl,type|ip|max:64|nullable',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}

dd("valid");
```

As you may see either all fields are required and be valid or all of the fields need to be empty.

How to make the validator allow either completely empty form inputs OR validate all of them (in case one of them contains input)?

Using the current code the validator doesn't validate the input, meaning only entering data into one field will return "valid" too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Validation: required\_with\_all condition always passing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324478/laravel-validation-required-with-all-condition-always-passing)

Comment: In short: `host => required_with_all:...` means that host is required if all the other fields are there. Host being there does not make other fields be required.

Comment: @apokryfos Any idea how to get this fixed?

Comment: Split to individual required whens