# Laravel Validation: required_with or required_with_all condition always passing

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

A similar post was made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324478/laravel-validation-required-with-all-condition-always-passing), but still it does not work in my case.

```
$v = \Validator::make($keys, [
            'overall' => 'required',
            'taste' => 'sometimes|required_with_all:freshness, quantity, value',
            'freshness' => 'sometimes|required_with_all:taste, quantity, value',
            'quantity' => 'sometimes|required_with_all:taste, freshness, value',
            'value' => 'sometimes|required_with_all: taste, quantity, freshness'
        ]);

dd($v->fails()); //-> false should be true
```

I'm trying to summarise what I'm doing:

- I have a rating system for different types of offers
- "overall" is always required, does not matter which offer type it is.
- An offer like food has rating types of "overall, taste, freshness, quantity and value"
- However, because there are many offer types "taste, freshness, quantity, and value" are not the only rating types. In future, there will be more (e.g. rating of an ebook (you won't rate the taste etc.))
- "taste, freshness, quantity and value" are only optional, but if only one exists everything should be required.

I tried to do it with "required_with", but it doesn't work.

My example array is:

```
array:4 [
  "overall" => 0
  "freshness" => 1
  "quantity" => 2
  "value" => 3
]
```

With "taste" missing.

So what am I doing wrong?

If I understand the docs completely:

> **required_with_all:foo,bar,...** The field under validation must be present only if all of the other specified fields are present.

That means if:

E.g. 'taste' => 'sometimes|required_with_all:freshness, quantity, value', means that when freshness, quantity, value are present, and param 'taste' is not present, then the validation error will occur.

But it does not...

Answer (score 1):

> **sometimes** : field will only be validated if it is present in the
>   data array.

Since `taste` is not presented in your example array it will not validate. Try without `sometimes`

`'taste' => 'required_with_all:freshness, quantity, value'`

Comment: Okay stupid me! In my testing, it works with `required_with` but I still receive a status of 200 when I'm using `required_with_all`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Shadrix What is the validation string you are using now ? & r u testing with the same example array?

Comment: Yes didn't change anything. Tried it with ->validate() but still no exception thrown